# Generate MD5 hash of running process

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem that i do not know how is it possible to do in C#.
So i have a running process, but after start i remove the execution file or exchange / modify it.

How is it possible to get the running processes file content and generate an md5 hash from it?

I can get the process list, but i cant get the context of it.

Can you give me some tips or maybe some code?

I tried to find the answer in the google / etc., but unfortunately i didnt find a solution for it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Edit your question and try to give a better description of your situation/requirements. Also, some example code may help (but don't overdo it)

Comment: You cannot. If the file is not there, you can't get its contents.

Comment: question is clear answer is hard;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I suppose, there is no solution for your problem.
Because of address space layout randomization and other security and non-security features of ram you'll never get reliable results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules[0].FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Run powershell in background and fetch the output from this script:

```
foreach ($proc in get-process) { try { Get-FileHash $proc.path -Algorithm MD5 -ErrorAction stop } catch { $proc.name | out-file c:\error.log -Append } }
```

Comment: Please consider using the notation for code - for your code in this answer

Comment: not option if file renamed powershell not able to find what not exists; need option to get memory bytes and back to file, but not sure if windows keep that mem without changes or cleanups ....

Answer (score 0):

did you try dump process with windows (or visual studio tools) and check what bytes exists inside....
I will start with that option

---

for my needs https://github.com/glmcdona/Process-Dump create most similar executable not same, but most of bytes inside main body correct.